# Solving a factorial equation

Tags: number-theory, factorial

Prove that the only solution to $k! +m! =n!$ is
$k = 1, m = 1, n = 2$

How would you go about this? I can't seem to figure out where to start.

Comment: The idea is that factorial grow really fast. So if $m\le k$ you will usually have $k!<m!+k!<(k+1)!$. Can you turn that into a proof of the result?

Comment: Are the integers supposed to be non-zero? E.g. $k=0,m=0,n=2$ also satisfy the equation.

Comment: Just divide both sides by $\min(k,m)$! and....

Comment: BTW.... you could have come up with a better title.  "How do I prove that this is true?" could stand to be a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $n>k,m$.

- $n>2\to 2n!=n!+n!>2\,k!+2\,m!$; there is no solution.
- $n=2\to1!+1!=2!$

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are also other solutions, e.g. $m=k=0,n=2$.

Assuming now that we are looking for solutions $n,m,k\neq0$. Also note that $n\geq2$.

Next by assuming  $k!\ge m!$ :
$$k!+m!\leq k!+k!=2k! \iff n! \leq 2k!$$
$$\iff \dfrac{n!}{k!} \leq 2,$$

from which the result follows. The final reasoning is left for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume, wolog, $k\le m$ and you divide by $k!$ you get:

$1 +  [(k+1).....m]= [(k+1).....m][(m+1)....n]$

Which is only possilbe if $[(k+1).....m] =1$.

Which is $k < m$ means $k=0$ and $m=1$.

......

Just finesse a bit allow for $k = m$ and divide allow "$[(k+1).....m]$" to be $1$ you get, if you divide by $k!=m!$:

$1 + 1= [(m+1)....n] = 2$

which means either $n = m+1=2$ or $2=(m+1)(m+2)=(m+1)n$

which means $m=k=1$ and $n=2$ or $m=k=0$ and $n=2$.

So only solutions are $0! + 0! = 2=2!$

$0! + 1! = 2!$

or

$1! + 1! = 2!$.

Comment: More simply, you can consider that $n!\ge n\,m!$ and conclude that there is no solution with $n>2$.

Comment: ... becuase $2m! \ge k! + m! \ge nm!$.... yeah that works too.  Not sure what is wrong with my brain this morning, but... I have a harder time "seeing" that.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but when it comes to factoring, multiplication is "atomic" and addition isn't, so its harder to "see" addition than division unless I actively *look* for it.

Comment: Here the factorial is such a fast growing function that you can't fill the gap between two successive of them. $2^n$ is the limit growth rate.